# How can I access other Users in Meteor which are created with Meteor accounts and are currently not logged in?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have tried with autopublish and still I am unable to get other users.

Answer (score 1):

Meteor.users.find() is the basic method you're looking for, and you can specify the return fields as you need using the Meteor.users.find({}, {FIELDNAMEONE: 1, FIELDNAMETWO: 1, ...}) syntax where you'd replace the FIELDNAMEs with what you want to have as part of the return.

With autopublish still enabled, you should be able to write a helper like `users: function(){return Meteor.users.find()}` in your template that will return your users. Blaze can iterate over that using {{#each}} to put whatever content you're interested in on the page.

Comment: Yes I know that I can pass other filters on that query, currently my query is: 
Meteor.users.findOne({
                        'emails.0.address':'alreadyExisting@tradeboox.com'
                    })
which returns undefined if alreadyExisting@tradeboox.com is not logged in.

Comment: It doesn't seem 100% clear in the documentation, but I have the same problem when just relying on autopublish. I added a `Meteor.publish("users", function(){return Meteor.users.find();});` and matching `Meteor.subscribe("users");` and it now returns in my example.

Comment: I missed the edit window above - the documentation actually is contradictory to the behavior observed: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_users states that autopublish makes the information available. (section just above the `Meteor.loggingIn` code block), however my test case was a brand new meteor project with accounts-ui and accounts-password added for testing.

Comment: I think he wants all the users that are `currently not logged in` as he states in his title. `Meteor.users.find()` returns a non reactive result

Comment: @Radu Chiriac Meteor.users.find().fetch() is returning the required data, so if I use this, I will have to loop all the users in the array for the email which will get complex if there are many users in the system.

Comment: And how can you tell he's loggedIn just by reading an email field?

Comment: I think you're focusing on the ability to see other concurrent users. I read the question having more to do with ability to see the Meteor.users collection beyond just yourself when logged into a Meteor app.

Answer (score 1):

Try using https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-user-status. This will eventually give you the state in each user is (and it's all reactive)